# Prime factors of a quadratic expression modulo $4$

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, prime-factorization

I am trying to prove something which needs this to be proved : $4x^2 - 108x + 1$ has not any prime factor of the form $p\equiv 3 (mod 4)$ where $x$ belongs to the sequence $a(n)$ satisfying $a(1) = 34$ , $a(n + 1) = 4a(n)^3 - 104a(n)^2 - 107a(n)$ for all positive integer $n$. I am stuck at this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I could not find an entry $x=a_n$ and a prime $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ with $p|4x^2-108x+1$ so far. But I do not know how to prove the desired statement so far either. My current guess is that it is true.

Comment: According to my calculations, no prime upto $10^6$ of the desired form can be a prime divisor of the desired numbers.

Comment: How do you got the limit 10^6? By Computer program? If yes, can you let me know the algorithm?

Comment: A computer program ; the idea is the following : For every prime $p$ , you determine the residues of the numbers modulo $p$ until a repitition occurs. At this point, the sequence of residues becomes periodic. If $0$ did not occur until this point, it will never occur. But a real proof would be that all the numbers can be written as the sum of two numbers, $a^2+b^2$, with coprime $a$ and $b$. But I have no idea yet how this can be done.